# STM32 randomly loses bytes during simultaneous USART sending and receiving

Tags: stm32, interrupt, keil, usart

I connected STM32F407VE to an external CAN device(TCAN4550). The MCU receives command from PC and transmits received CAN data to PC via USART. With cyclic CAN messages active, MCU loses a byte here and there.
A client service told me that sending and receiving of USART shared the same DR and normally the 'ask and answer' mode was used. I guess my problem happens when both sending and receiving occurs in one interrupt.
Here are part of my codes in Keil5:

```
#define sizeUSART1TX    4096
#define sizeUSART1RX    256

static unsigned char USART1TxBuf[sizeUSART1TX];
static char USART1RxBuf[sizeUSART1RX];
static unsigned short USART1TxIdx0=0, USART1TxIdx1=0, USART1RxIdx=0;

static void USART1SendChar(char *buf, unsigned short cnt)
{
    if(USART1Act==0) return;
    for (unsigned short idx1 = 0; idx1 < cnt; ++idx1)
    {
        USART1TxBuf[USART1TxIdx0++] = buf[idx1];
        if (USART1TxIdx0 == sizeUSART1TX)
            USART1TxIdx0 = 0;
    }
    if ((USART1->CR1 & 1 << 7) == 0)    //TXEIE
        USART1->CR1 |= 1 << 7;
}

void USART1_IRQHandler(void)
{
    if (USART1->SR & (1 << 5))  //RXNE, reset by reading DR
    {
        USART1RxBuf[USART1RxIdx++] = USART1->DR;

        if (USART1RxBuf[USART1RxIdx-1] == 10)   //command end
        {
            ......      //actions

            USART1SendChar(USART1RxBuf, USART1RxIdx);   //confirm the command
            memset(USART1RxBuf, 0, sizeUSART1RX);
            USART1RxIdx = 0;
        }
    }
    if ((USART1->SR & 1<<7) && (USART1->CR1 & 1<<7))    //TXE and TXEIE
    {
        USART1->DR = USART1TxBuf[USART1TxIdx1++];   //writing DR reset interrupts
        if (USART1TxIdx1 == sizeUSART1TX)
            USART1TxIdx1 = 0;
        if (USART1TxIdx1 == USART1TxIdx0)
            USART1->CR1 &= ~(1<<7); //turning off TXEIE
    }
}

int main()
{
//USART
    USART_InitTypeDef USART_InitStructure;
    RCC->APB2ENR |= RCC_APB2ENR_USART1EN | RCC_APB2Periph_SYSCFG;
    //PA9
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin   = GPIO_Pin_9;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode  = GPIO_Mode_AF;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_PuPd  = GPIO_PuPd_UP;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStructure);
    //PA10
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_10;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStructure);

    GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOA, GPIO_PinSource9, GPIO_AF_USART1);
    GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOA, GPIO_PinSource10, GPIO_AF_USART1);

    NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannel = USART1_IRQn;
    NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelPreemptionPriority = 1;
    NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelSubPriority = 0;
    NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelCmd = ENABLE;
    NVIC_Init(&NVIC_InitStructure);

    USART_DeInit(USART1);
    USART_InitStructure.USART_BaudRate = 115200;
    USART_InitStructure.USART_WordLength = USART_WordLength_8b;
    USART_InitStructure.USART_StopBits = USART_StopBits_1;
    USART_InitStructure.USART_Parity = USART_Parity_No;
    USART_InitStructure.USART_HardwareFlowControl = USART_HardwareFlowControl_None;
    USART_InitStructure.USART_Mode = USART_Mode_Rx | USART_Mode_Tx;
    USART_Init(USART1, &USART_InitStructure);

    USART_ITConfig(USART1, USART_IT_TXE, DISABLE);
    USART_ITConfig(USART1, USART_IT_RXNE, ENABLE);
    USART_Cmd(USART1, ENABLE);
    USART_DMACmd(USART1, USART_DMAReq_Tx, ENABLE);
    USART1->SR = ~(0x00F0);     //clear interrupts

    while(1){}
}
```

Is it possible to realize true full duplex for USART?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> With cyclic CAN messages active, MCU loses a byte here and there.

If the CAN uses lengthy interrupts (longer than Rx character duration plus any spacing between characters) and those have the same or higher priority than the UART ISR, then some of the Rx characters may get simply lost due to not being picked from UART_DR before next character arrives.

Check UART Rx Overrun in the ISR.

Comment: I'll add an ORE check in the ISR. I found some instruction saying that such byte loss happens when DR is 'locked' by the ISR and it takes too much time to finish the ISR. So I made the process short and set all interrupts to the same preemption priority(the sub priorities are different but I don't know when they make a difference). The byte loss happens in the other register before DR and I don't know its size and property. Do you mean the byte loss can also happen outside of the USART ISR?

Comment: > DR is 'locked' by the ISR

I don't know what that means. Post link.

> the sub priorities are different but I don't know when they make a difference
In case of two interrupts getting pending at the same time, this decides which will be served first.
Point is, that CAN ISR must not be too long so that USART Rx could be handled for all Rx characters; or USART ISR must have higher "preemtion" priority than CAN ISR.

> The byte loss happens in the other register before DR
I don't know what that means, please explain.

Comment: The link is not in English and I'm not sure I can find it again. If I understand you right, any data sent to MCU via USART must be received immediately. So I need to decrease the operations or set higher priority to USART? About the sub priority, what I don't understand is "at the same time". Does it mean "in the same system clock time quantum"? It's a really low probability event.

Comment: _So I need to decrease the operations_ I don't know what that means. _or set higher priority to USART_ if characters got lost because of other ISR being lengthy, yes.

Comment: _About the sub priority, what I don't understand is "at the same time". Does it mean "in the same system clock time quantum"? It's a really low probability event._ Yes that would be a low probability event, but it also happens when interrupt A and B gets pending during execution of interrupt C with priority equal or higher than A and B; or during a period when interrupts are disabled globally.